# How would I go about creating the following tables?

Tags: tables

[image: First Table]

[image: Second Table]

I would like to know how to create such tables in latex. Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you make some attempts?

Comment: Not yet. Quite honestly I am very new to LaTeX, and I feel very lost

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag you to my response @egreg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For fun, I use stacks of `\fcolorbox`es and `\fbox`es.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=-.5pt\relax\fboxrule=1pt\relax
\ensurestackMath{\Longunderstack{m_1 m_2 m_3 m_4}} \fbox{%
\fboxrule=.5pt\fboxsep=2.5pt\relax
\Longunderstack[l]{\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[106pt]{124}}} {} {} \,M}%
\Longunderstack{{} \fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[10pt]{8}}}}%
\Longunderstack{{} {} \fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[8pt]{6}}}}%
\Longunderstack{{} {} {} \fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[8pt]{6}}}}%
}\par
\bigskip
\ensurestackMath{\Longunderstack{m_1 m_2 m_3 m_4}} \stackunder{\fbox{%
\fboxrule=.5pt\fboxsep=2.5pt\relax
\Longunderstack[l]{\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[33pt]{36}}} {} {} \,M$'$}%
\Longunderstack{{} \fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[33pt]{36}}}}%
\Longunderstack{{} {} \fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[33pt]{36}}}}%
\Longunderstack{{} {} {} \fcolorbox{black}{gray}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[33pt]{36}}}}%
}}{$N=500$ samples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! Would you by any chance know how to create the second figure? Thank you!

Comment: sorry I forgot to tag you into the response @Steven